# PHP !isset() and empty() returns true for AJAX post data even if it is set

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I wonder why `!isset($var)` and `empty($var)` in this case returns `TRUE` even when it's not.

Actually, this problem has been resolved by using `$var == NULL` instead, but that's not the question. I have read similar problems, but the issue is always about the data type; and I am sure that I got the data type right through logging and dumping every variables, and by changing the condition to `$var == NULL`, it works and returned `FALSE`.

EDIT: here is the HTML:

```
<td><?php echo $match['partic1_name'] ?></td>
<td><input type="number" max="2" id="partic1_score" style="width: 80px;" class="form-control score-input" value="<?php echo $match['partic1_score']; ?>"></td>
<td><input type="number" max="2" id="partic2_score" style="width: 80px;" class="form-control score-input" value="<?php echo $match['partic2_score']; ?>"></td>
<td><?php echo $match['partic2_name'] ?></td>
<td><button id="<?php echo $match['id'] ?>" type="submit" class="btn btn-success score-submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Submit</button></td>
```

Here is the AJAX part (full):

```
$(".score-submit").click(function () {
        var field1 = $(this).parent().parent().find("#partic1_score");
        var field2 = $(this).parent().parent().find("#partic2_score");
        var s1 = parseInt(field1.val(), 10);
        var s2 = parseInt(field2.val(), 10);
        var t = s1 + s2;

        if (t > 3 || t < 2) {
            alert("Invalid Scores. The score must be 2-0, 2-1, 0-2, 1-2, or 1-1");
        } else {
            var target = '<?php echo base_url("index.php/matches/submit/") ?>';
            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            var self = this;
            $.ajax({
                url: target,
                type: "POST",
                data: {'id': id, 'score1': s1, 'score2': s2},
                success: function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    if (response == 1) {
                        field1.prop('disabled', true);
                        field2.prop('disabled', true);
                        $(self).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    } else {
                        alert("Failed to do the operation.");
                    }
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert("Something went wrong. Please refresh the page before trying again.");
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Controller:

```
public function submit() {
    $id = $this->input->post('id');
    $score1 = $this->input->post('score1');
    $score2 = $this->input->post('score2');
    echo $this->matches_model->submit_scores($id, $score1, $score2);
}
```

Model:

```
public function submit_scores($id, $score1, $score2) {
    if (empty($id) || empty($score1) || empty($score2)) { // <-- Here`s the culprit
        return 0;
    }

    $data = array(
        'partic1_score' => $score1,
        'partic2_score' => $score2
    );
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('matches', $data);
    return ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Comment: what are the values of s1 and s2?

Comment: `id` is the id of the match, `s1` and `s2` is the value inside `input`.

Comment: what is the result of `echo $id .', ' . $score1 . ', ' . $score2; exit;` before `empty` conditions ? add output in question

Comment: depends on the value of `input` tag (added to the question). For example, I once tested by dumping the response through `console.log`; it return `id => "17"`, `score1 => "2"`, `score2 => "0"`

Comment: if any of the value is `0` then in php `empty` function return true. Look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) for more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [**docs**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

In php, if any value is coming as `0`, then `empty` function return as `true`

So if you like to validate `0` values too, then change your `if` conditions like below:

**Try this:**

```
if ($id == '' || $score1 == '' || $score2 == '') {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OK, that explains it if I use `empty()`. I just tested using `isset()`, but it returns `true` even if I have or do not have `0`.

Comment: Php `isset()` function check for the varialbe is set or not, it will always returns true because all variables are always set via ajax call

Comment: whoops, I mean `!isset()`. Sorry

Comment: you mean `if (!isset($id) || !isset($score1) || !isset($score2)) {` ? return true?

Comment: Yeah, basically I want to check if any of those variables are empty or not set and return 0 or `false`. I just wonder why I have to use `$var == NULL`.

Comment: have you tried above `if` conditions? it will work if any of the variable is blank or 0, In your case you don't need to check for `!isset()` because ajax request always have all those variables in post.

Comment: Ah, so I just need to worry if those vars are empty. Thank you, you're very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Vars in ajax **id** **s1** and **s2** are simply empty.

In php they are setted, but empty

Comment: `id` is the id of the match, `s1` and `s2` is the value inside `input`. I am sure it is not empty through `var_dump()`.

Comment: If **s1** or **s2** has zero in it - it's marked as empty

Comment: OK, that explains it if I use `empty()`. I just tested using `isset()`, but it returns `true` even if I have or do not have `0`.

Comment: **isset()** only checks if variable exists
Try **isset($_POST["s3"])** and u'll receive **false**

Comment: Sorry, I mean `!isset()`